# Java EHCache on Windows slower than on Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, ehcache

I'm using EHCache 3.3.1 on java in my project which is being ran on NetBeans IDE. However, I noticed a strange thing. When I run the same code on windows operating system it's 10 times slower than when I run it on ubuntu, so I made the following test:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.ehcache.CacheManager;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder;
import org.ehcache.Cache;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.units.MemoryUnit;
public class EHCacheManager {
    private static CacheManager instance;
    static{
                instance = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
                  .with(CacheManagerBuilder.persistence(System.getProperty("user.dir") +
                    File.separator + "CacheFiles"))
                    .build(true);
    }
    private EHCacheManager(){
    }
    public static CacheManager getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
public class EHCacheTest {
    private static CacheManager cacheManager = EHCacheManager.getInstance();
    private static Cache<String, Integer> cacheMap =    
                cacheManager.createCache("HostInfoMap", 
                CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class,
                Integer.class,ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                .heap(500, MemoryUnit.MB)
                .offheap(600, MemoryUnit.MB)
                .disk(1, MemoryUnit.GB))
                .build());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println("Starting fill the cache..");
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
            cacheMap.put("number" + i, i);
        }
        System.err.println("Finished fill the cache..");
        System.err.flush();
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that this code runs on about 1 second on ubuntu, while it takes more than 12 seconds to run on windows. I'm working on a project where the execution time is absolutely important for me. Also, I can't use a simple map because I need to store large amounts of data within my map. Is there a specific reason why this is happening? Or did I use a wrong set up for my cache? Or should I use some different library to store my data as a map?

Comment: The answer to this can depend so much on the environment that it's going to be hard to give. Are you sure it is not simply an anti virus making a mess of the filesystem for example? Can you take regular thread dumps during the execution on both platforms and see if you notice a difference?

Comment: As @LouisJacomet said, I would suspect the anti-virus. Or simply a slower disk on Windows. You should run a profiler on the execution.

Comment: I tried running this program on 2 PCs with windows (one with anti-virus and one without), and 2 PCs with linux, the same result held regardless of the anti-virus.